# Using swap space with jemalloc

Tags: c++, memory-management

If I have a SSD device on my machine, is it possible to use it as swap space and do the following:

Allocate say, a hash table in memory, using jemalloc, and keep populating it over and above the system's memory, and let jemalloc swap out pages to the swap device and bring them in, as needed?

Comment: Sure. But for maximum performance you'd want some control over when accesses missed RAM, wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, the use case is for high quality SSDs, where RAM misses won't hurt much. So, is this possible? If so, could you direct me to some resources?

Comment: @AlanStokes: Could you elaborate on how this can be achieved?